# Script to gentle scroll to a section of the page generates an error on javascript

Tags: javascript

Newbie:

I created this script to gentle scroll in any section of the page:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
```

Every works fine but something really bothers me. On my console, I receive an error notification:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

Every time I click on an internal link that has the href=#. The script still works and doesn't interact with my code, so I'm happy with that but not entirely.

I was thinking about an if statement to exclude the error, essentially to fire my effect only when something exists, but this is the document that we are talking about, so I don't think is possible.

Any though about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element has a href of "#" before executing any code or doing any animating.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
   if($(this).attr('href')!=="#"){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is quite simple. The selector `a[href^="#"]` finds all anchors whose `href` attribute starts with `#`, including those that are *only* `#`. You later use that `href` as a selector (`$($.attr(this, 'href'))`). By itself, `#` is not a valid selector.

You probably want to target all anchors whose `href` attribute starts with `#` but is not *only* `#`, which can be accomplished thusly:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"])', function(event) {
  console.log('heavy');
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Just a pound (should not log anything to the console)</a><br>
<a href="#more">More than a pound (should log "heavy" to the console, and take you to Heavy)</a><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="more">Heavy</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `element.scrollIntoView()`

Also add this to your css to make the scroll effect smooth:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```